# Javascript - Switch always returning default

Tags: javascript

In a project I am converting scores to grades. In order to do so I have used a switch statement that checks if the score is between certain thresholds. The problem is that every case returns the default value.

The case arguments seem to be correct to me. Because if I test them outside of the switch statement they return a correct true or false value `console.log(score >= 1 && score < 1.8)`

```js
const getLabelForScore = (score) => {
  let label = '';
  switch (score) {
    case (score < 1):
      label = 'F';
      break;
    case (score >= 1 && score < 1.8):
      label = 'E';
      break;
    case (score >= 1.8 && score < 3):
      label = 'D';
      break;
    case (score >= 3 && score < 4.2):
      label = 'C';
      break;
    case (score >= 4.2 && score < 5):
      label = 'B';
      break;
    case (score >= 5):
      label = 'A';
      break;
    default:
      label = 'No Grade';
  }

  return {
    score: score,
    label,
  };
};

console.log(getLabelForScore(3.15));
console.log(getLabelForScore(2.50));
console.log(getLabelForScore(4.75));
```

Comment: `switch-case` statements don't work like that in JavaScript. You have to provide a number value inside your case statements. For this use-case you would be best advised to use `if-elseif`

Comment: You can do `switch(true)` though, and then have the conditions in your cases, see https://medium.com/trabe/using-switch-true-in-javascript-986e8ad8ae4f

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+range+conditions+in+switch+case) of [Expression inside switch case statement](/q/3463833/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `switch` isn't comparing what you think.  Consider the value here:

```
switch (score) {
```

So `score` is `3.15`.  Then consider the value here:

```
case (score >= 3 && score < 4.2):
```

The `case` value is `true`.  Since `3.15 === true` is `false`, the `case` is not satisfied.

You *can* potentially make this work by doing:

```
switch (true) {
```

Then your case conditions should compare correctly.  But honestly I think this makes the code less clear.  The semantics of what you're expressing are "if X then A, else if Y then B, else..."  There's nothing inherently wrong with `if` statements:

```
if (score < 1) {
  label = 'F';
} else if (score >= 1 && score < 1.8) {
  label = 'E';
} //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have changed the switch to true and it worked!

Comment: `} else if (score < 1.8) {` (and continuing like that) would suffice, as `>= 1` is given by failing the first if.